# Bluetooth mouse randomly stopped working

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, bluetooth

I know there are similar problems but my case is weired and I don't even know what would be wrong here.

First, My mouse is a [HP Wireless Bluetooth Mouse Z5000](https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/p/hp-wireless-bluetooth-mouse-z5000-hpz5000btm). It worked find before until recently I reinstalled Windows 10 20H2.

But now it randomly stopped response. Usually this happens whilst I scrolling down on a web page using the roller wheel.

That mouse was connected via Bluetooth, and since this is a PC a Bluetooth dongle is needed. The dongle is plugged in a USB 3.0 hub with 4 ports. The dongle is older than the mouse, but younger than the hub. I don't know what version of Bluetooth it would support but it is not like a 5.0 device.

Now it is the weird part. The mouse will get back to work when I plug another USB mouse to a spare port of the hub. When this happens, the page I was browsing would suddenly scrolled a little bit. I can then unplug the extra mouse and the HP mouse will remain working.

Note it is not likely be a problem of Bluetooth power control - it happens when I am actively using the mouse. Also this is not a matter of distance - my PC is right underneath the mouse. Battery is also not a problem - It happens when using a new AA battery.

What could be the reason for all this?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely a problem of the hub - I moved the Bluetooth dongle to another port and the problem is gone.

I think this explains why plugging another mouse to the hub worked. However, only plugging mouse would work, any other devices does not, which makes it interesting.